# Batch file - passing path name as parameter in command line

Tags: batch-file, parameters

I want to copy from source to destination only the files with `.txt` extension. I want to give as parameters in commandline the path name - `source` and the path name - `destination`. Here is my batch file Script.bat:

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal 
set /p source =
set /p destination=
FOR %%f IN (*.txt) DO XCOPY "%source%"\"%%f" "%destination%" /m /y /d /s
```

I want to call this batch file in cmd so:

```
cmd> Script.bat "SourceFolder" "DestinationFolder"
```

But it doesn't work!
Thank you!

Comment: Why a batch file when xcopy works `xcopy c:\source\*.txt c:\dest` or [Robocopy](http://www.computerhope.com/robocopy.htm) `robocopy c:\hope c:\hope2 *.txt`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing correctness of `/m /y /d /s` [xcopy](http://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html) switches this script could work:

```
@echo off
setlocal
if "%~1"=="" goto :error empty 1
if "%~2"=="" goto :error empty 2
set "source=%~1"
if not exist "%source%\" goto :error not exist 1
set "destination=%~2"
if not exist "%destination%\" goto :error not exist 2
xcopy "%source%\*.txt" "%destination%\" /m /y /d /s

goto :eof
:error
echo wrong parameters %*
goto :eof
```

See also next resource: [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try.  It may not be entirely correct, but it should help you get started.

```
@echo off
setlocal 
set /p source = 
set /p destination= 
xcopy /m /y /d /s "%~source%\*.txt" "%~destination%\"
```